# Publish multiple apks in google play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

Guided by [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) manual I'm trying to publish three different apks for different screen sizes.
I've created following filters:
For small screens:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"/>
```

For normal and large screens:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="540"/>
```

For xlarge screens:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

In rest all three manifests looks the same.
I've uploaded this apks to google play and filters seems to be correct. 
 
**The problem:** When I install my application to different devices it allways installs version for normal and large screens, I've tested even on Galaxy S4 and HTC One with full hd screens. 
 
I've only one warning in play console: `Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.`
This is how my play console looks like: [image]

Does anybody has any ideas what is wrong with my configuration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not able to comment yet, I have to use the Answer-function.

I guess "large, small & xlarge" mean the dp-value. But the idea behind density-independent-pixels(dp) is to bring the same experience to users who have a 4 Inch phone with 480*800 and full hd(1920*1080) Resolution. So maybe you should test your app on an 8 or 10 Inch tablet and see what you get, because every 4 inch phone should have the same dp-width, but a 10 inch tablet even with the same resolution should not.

[this could be interesting for you to read](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) about density-independent-pixels in android

Hope I could help you

Comment: I know about supporting multiple screen resolution in one apk. But I need to publish different apks for different screen resolution.